# info.plist preferences for application search on iPhone

Tags: iphone, search, info.plist, springboard

My application name is `TestApplication` which is my bundle display name and my application PRODUCTNAME is `MyTestApplication`.

When I search my application on `Simulator/Device` with keyword "My" it doesn't search the application.

How can I make searchable my application with keyword "My"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hours research I have found that The iPhone Spotlight searches the applications with 2 names 
1- Bundle Display Name 
2- Apple Store Name
So If we set the name in appstore MyTestApplication then searching with word "My" would also search the app TestApplication.